# Sort serialized object alphabetically (Java)

Tags: java, json, serialization

Say I have the following Json string which is a serialized object:

```
{"ID":27,"Name":"QA14ADMINOPM201","OSBits":null,"OSName":null, "SupportedLocales": "NA","Global"],"MachineSpec":null,"Proxy":null}
```

Is there a way for me to alphabetize the string by field so that the string becomes:

```
{"ID":27,"MachineSpec":null,"Name":"QA14ADMINOPM201","OSBits":null,"OSName":null,"Proxy":null, "SupportedLocales":["NA","Global"]}
```

And also make it so that if there were another object field within this object, all of this object's fields would also be sorted?

Comment: You can always write a program that parses the JSON String, sorts the dictionaries and creates a new sorted JSON String.

Comment: A JSON object is like a Java HashMap: the keys don't have any order. So what's the point?

Comment: may be this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493413/how-can-i-sort-my-json-object-based-on-key

Answer (score 0):

It's been looooooooog time.
But jaskson can do it: 
spring.jackson.mapper.sort-properties-alphabetically=true